# if i add LIKE i want the same output of my query count

Tags: mysql

if i add "AND e.first_name LIKE '%Faith%' " this is the output [Output of query with LIKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDA99.png) but i want the same output of the query below

```
    SELECT COUNT(sd.id) as 'shortlisted_count',

    sm.filter_details_id as id

    FROM shortlisted_details sd

    INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id= sd.employee_id

    INNER JOIN shortlisted_master sm ON sm.id=sd.shortlisted_master_id

    WHERE sd.is_disqualified=0 AND sm.filter_details_id = 136

        GROUP BY sm.id
```

[output that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTXPo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the criteria `sm.filter_details_id = 136` to the `ON` clause of the second join:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(sd.id) AS shortlisted_count,
    sm.filter_details_id AS id
FROM shortlisted_details sd
INNER JOIN employees e
    ON e.id = sd.employee_id AND
       e.first_name LIKE '%Faith%'
INNER JOIN shortlisted_master sm
    ON sm.id = sd.shortlisted_master_id AND
       sm.filter_details_id = 136
WHERE
    sd.is_disqualified = 0
GROUP BY
    sm.id;
```

The reason why this change may fix the counting problem is that it prevents records from prematurely being filtered off in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i want to add (AND e.first_name LIKE '%Faith%) but the output that i want is in the link "output that i want" :(

Comment: I have corrected every mistake that I saw.  You provided no sample data, therefore it is difficult to answer.